# Configure Manuel container IntelliJ Arquillian Wildfly

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, jboss-arquillian

I m using intelliJ for runnig a junit arquillian test.

The problem is my test works with maven command but not with arquillian

```
mvn package -P=arq-wildlfy-managed
```

Here my pom :

```
 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Arquillian BOM (Bill Of Materials). -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit regression testing framework. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${version.junit}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<profiles>

    <!-- Arquillian WildFly managed profile -->
    <profile>
        <id>arq-wildfly-managed</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.wildfly}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <testResources>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                </testResource>
            </testResources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>unpack</id>
                            <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>unpack</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                                        <version>${version.org.wildfly}</version>
                                        <type>zip</type>
                                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <!-- Arquillian WildFly remote profile -->
    <profile>
        <id>arq-widlfly-remote</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.wildfly}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

</profiles>

<dependencies>

    <!-- JUnit regression testing framework. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUnit Container Implementation for the Arquillian Project -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

The xml file arquillian:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

<!-- Sets the protocol which is how Arquillian talks and executes the tests inside the container -->
<defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />

<!-- Configuration to be used when the WidlFly remote profile is active -->
<container qualifier="widlfly-remote">
    <configuration>
        <property name="managementAddress">127.0.0.1</property>
        <property name="managementPort">9990</property>
        <property name="username">admin</property>
        <property name="password">admin</property>
    </configuration>
</container>

<!-- Configuration to be used when the WildFly managed profile is active -->
<container qualifier="widlfly-managed" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="jbossHome">${jbossHome:target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final}</property>
        <property name="allowConnectingToRunningServer">false</property>
        <property name="javaVmArguments">-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=10000 -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</property>
        <property name="managementPort">19990</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

I would like to run the Junit test arquillian from intelliJ. I don't know how I can configure the manuel container , to let arquillian point the wildfly container located at \target\wildfly-8.1.0.Final.

[image]

When I run the test with this manuel container , i have this error.

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.ConfigurationException: jbossHome 'target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final' must exist

at org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.deployment.Validate.configurationDirectoryExists(Validate.java:139)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.DistributionContainerConfiguration.validate(DistributionContainerConfiguration.java:99)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.managed.ManagedContainerConfiguration.validate(ManagedContainerConfiguration.java:73)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.createDeployableConfiguration(ContainerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.setup(ContainerImpl.java:181)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$7.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:149)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$7.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:145)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:255)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.setupContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:144)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$1.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:62)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$1.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:55)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forEachContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:209)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.setupContainers(ContainerLifecycleController.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeSuite(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:68)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:104)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Any clue ?

Answer (score 5):

I found how I can run Junit Test Arquillian with the Manuel container.

First,

- You have to specify that you will run the Junit with a manual
  Container
- Keep the manual configuration empty

In the arquillian xml add :

```
  <property name="jbossHome">${project.basedir}\target\wildfly-8.1.0.Final</property>
```

Then on the pom add :

```
<build>
<testResources>
<testResource>
<directory>src/test/resources</directory>
<filtering>true</filtering>
</testResource>
```

Then run the arquillian junit test

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

You can add a new manual configuration in intellij via the config button. Whereafter you can add (via the + button) a manual configuration as shown in the image.
In the manual configuration I added the JBOSS_HOME environment variable with the path to the wildfly location and disabled the java property module.path. See also the image.

[intellij configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueQDe.jpg)